# Need to convert a JavaScript Alert to Display in a DIV instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

The site I am working on has a custom label over the input file and the thing about that is that it doesn't show which file is selected. I found some JavaScript code that does it, but it does it with a popup alert. I need for the div to only show if they chose a file.

I saw some other similar solutions on this website, but I couldn't make it work. My JavaScript knowledge is very limited, pretty much copy paste and switch out a variable so I can do it more than once on a page.

Here is the JS

```
function get_filename(obj) {

var file = obj.value;
alert(file);
```

}

My Html

```
<form id="myForm2" method="post"> 
    <label class="myLabel">
         <input type="file" name="UploadMedia" accept="image/jpeg" onchange="get_filename(this);">
         <span>Upload Media</span>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="postit" value="Post" class="postbutton" />
</form>
```

I need it go appear in something like this

```
<div id="filechosen">&nbsp;</div>
```

Instead of an onscreen popup.

The alert also shows the fake path that Chrome does because of security, if you could put code in there to get rid of that too, that would be very helpful.

If anyone could help, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('filechosen').textContent = file;`.

Comment: Andy Thank you for this! It's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A good ready made alternative to alert is [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)
Instead of:

```
alert("text");
```

you would do:

```
sweetAlert("text");
```

This gives a much prettier alert box.

For the second part of your question:
To replace text in a string you use the replace keyword:

```
var a ="SomeTextToRemoveAndTing";
var b = a.replace("SomeTextToRemove", "");
// b = "AndTing";
```

Comment: Chris this SweetAlert is pretty nice, I will keep that link for future use. Thank you for the replace code.

Comment: Chris I was able to figure it out, combined it with Andy's answer above
var file = obj.value;
var res = file.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
document.getElementById('filechosen').textContent = res;
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text content on that particular element:

```
var filechosen = document.getElementById('filechosen');
filechosen.textContent = file;
```